# AVAssetWriter error when AVCaptureSession camera input is changed

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avassetwriter, avcapturedevice

I use AVCaptureSession getting live data from camera and AVCaptureVideoDataOutput & AVCaptureAudioDataOutput delegates in order to get live data frame by frame. (-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection). I sent sample buffer frames (CMSampleBufferRef) that are taken from captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection: method to the AVAssetWriter's appendSampleBuffer: method in order to save the taken buffers as video file. But AVAssetWriter instance's status becomes to AVAssetWriterStatusFailed when back camera is toggled to front camera and try to appendSampleBuffer: with the sample buffer that is received from front camera.

The exact error message is:

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo=0x176573f0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x175e9e50 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12710.)", NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12710)}

What can be the problem?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hi, I am also facing same issue. how did you solve this issue ?

Comment: i have posted my question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805863/changing-avcapturedeviceinput-leads-to-avassetwriterstatusfailed]. same issue i am facing. how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Hi Crazywood, i am not able to find why it shows `AVAssetWriterStatusFailed` . how you solved this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi Grey_Code, unfortunately i could not achieve to solve it, sometimes it fails but the error is unknown :(

Comment: OMG !!!!!!!, i believed you have solution for this.

Comment: Ok, anyways Thanks for your Reply Crazywood