# Changing AVCaptureDeviceInput leads to AVAssetWriterStatusFailed

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avassetwriter

I am trying to change the Camera View `Front` and `Back`.it is working well.if video is recorded without flipping with `Pause/Record` Option it is working fine.But if we `Flip Camera View` once then, further recording video is not saving which leads to `AVAssetWriterStatusFailed`-`The operation could not be completed`. Can anybody help me to find where i have gone wrong ? Below is my code.

### *Camera.m*

> ```
> - (void)flipCamera{
> NSArray * inputs = _session.inputs;
> for ( AVCaptureDeviceInput * INPUT in inputs ) {
>     AVCaptureDevice * Device = INPUT.device ;
>     if ( [ Device hasMediaType : AVMediaTypeVideo ] ) {
>         AVCaptureDevicePosition position = Device . position ; AVCaptureDevice * newCamera = nil ; AVCaptureDeviceInput * newInput = nil ;
>         if ( position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront )
>             newCamera = [ self cameraWithPosition : AVCaptureDevicePositionBack ] ;
>         else
>             newCamera = [ self cameraWithPosition : AVCaptureDevicePositionFront ] ; newInput = [ AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice : newCamera error : nil ] ;
>         // beginConfiguration ensures that pending changes are not applied immediately
>         [ _session beginConfiguration ] ;
>         [ _session removeInput : INPUT ] ;
>         [ _session addInput : newInput ] ;
>         // Changes take effect once the outermost commitConfiguration is invoked.
>         [ _session commitConfiguration ] ;
>         break ;
>     }
> }
> for ( AVCaptureDeviceInput * INPUT in inputs ) {
>     AVCaptureDevice * Device = INPUT.device ;
>     if ( [ Device hasMediaType : AVMediaTypeAudio ] ) {
>         // audio input from default mic
>         AVCaptureDevice* mic = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
>         AVCaptureDeviceInput* newInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:mic error:nil];
>         //            [_session addInput:micinput];
>         // beginConfiguration ensures that pending changes are not applied immediately
>         [ _session beginConfiguration ] ;
>         [ _session removeInput : INPUT ] ;
>         [ _session addInput : newInput ] ;
>         // Changes take effect once the outermost commitConfiguration is invoked.
>         [ _session commitConfiguration ] ;
>         break ;
>     }
> }
> }
>
> - ( AVCaptureDevice * ) cameraWithPosition : ( AVCaptureDevicePosition ) position
>  {
> NSArray * Devices = [ AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType : AVMediaTypeVideo ] ;
> for ( AVCaptureDevice * Device in Devices )
>     if ( Device . position == position )
>         return Device ;
> return nil ;
> }
>
> - (void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
> {
> BOOL bVideo = YES;
> @synchronized(self)
> {
>     if (!self.isCapturing  || self.isPaused)
>     {
>         return;
>     }
>     if (connection != _videoConnection)
>     {
>         bVideo = NO;
>     }
>     if ((_encoder == nil) && !bVideo)
>     {
>         CMFormatDescriptionRef fmt = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer);
>         [self setAudioFormat:fmt];
>         NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"capture%d.mp4", _currentFile];
>         NSString* path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
>         _encoder = [VideoEncoder encoderForPath:path Height:_cy width:_cx channels:_channels samples:_samplerate];
>     }
>     if (_discont)
>     {
>         if (bVideo)
>         {
>             return;
>         }
>         _discont = NO;
>         // calc adjustment
>         CMTime pts = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
>         CMTime last = bVideo ? _lastVideo : _lastAudio;
>         if (last.flags & kCMTimeFlags_Valid)
>         {
>             if (_timeOffset.flags & kCMTimeFlags_Valid)
>             {
>                 pts = CMTimeSubtract(pts, _timeOffset);
>             }
>             CMTime offset = CMTimeSubtract(pts, last);
>             NSLog(@"Setting offset from %s", bVideo?"video": "audio");
>             NSLog(@"Adding %f to %f (pts %f)", ((double)offset.value)/offset.timescale, ((double)_timeOffset.value)/_timeOffset.timescale, ((double)pts.value/pts.timescale));
>             // this stops us having to set a scale for _timeOffset before we see the first video time
>             if (_timeOffset.value == 0)
>             {
>                 _timeOffset = offset;
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 _timeOffset = CMTimeAdd(_timeOffset, offset);
>             }
>         }
>         _lastVideo.flags = 0;
>         _lastAudio.flags = 0;
>     }
>     // retain so that we can release either this or modified one
>     CFRetain(sampleBuffer);
>     if (_timeOffset.value > 0)
>     {
>         CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
>         sampleBuffer = [self adjustTime:sampleBuffer by:_timeOffset];
>     }
>     // record most recent time so we know the length of the pause
>     CMTime pts = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
>     CMTime dur = CMSampleBufferGetDuration(sampleBuffer);
>     if (dur.value > 0)
>     {
>         pts = CMTimeAdd(pts, dur);
>     }
>     if (bVideo)
>     {
>         _lastVideo = pts;
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         _lastAudio = pts;
>     }
> }
> // pass frame to encoder
> [_encoder encodeFrame:sampleBuffer isVideo:bVideo];
> CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
> }
> ```

### *Encoder.m*

> ```
>  - (BOOL) encodeFrame:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer isVideo:(BOOL)bVideo
>   {
>  if (CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer))
> {
>     if (_writer.status == AVAssetWriterStatusUnknown)
>     {
>         CMTime startTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
>         [_writer startWriting];
>         [_writer startSessionAtSourceTime:startTime];
>     }
>     if (_writer.status == AVAssetWriterStatusFailed)
>     {   // If Camera View is Flipped then Loop Enters inside this condition - writer error The operation could not be completed
>         NSLog(@"writer error %@", _writer.error.localizedDescription);
>         return NO;
>     }
>     if (bVideo)
>     {
>         if (_videoInput.readyForMoreMediaData == YES)
>         {
>             [_videoInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
>             return YES;
>         }
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         if (_audioInput.readyForMoreMediaData)
>         {
>             [_audioInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
>             return YES;
>         }
>     }
> }
> return NO;
> }
> ```

*Thanks in Advance.*

Comment: @3r1d - I am working on this same issue for 4 days. not able to track where is the issue ? can you help me out to track where i have gone wrong ?

Comment: Hey Grey_Code, look I have never used this library, but I will have a look later and if I come up with something I'll give you feedback. :)

Comment: did you ever solve this problem?  I am having the same exact issue...

Comment: Hi Grey_Code, I am having the same problem can you please guide me ?

Answer (score 8):

The problem is this line:

```
if (connection != _videoConnection)
    {
        bVideo = NO;
    }
```

When you change the camera a new videoConnection is created, I don't know where either how. But if you change this line like below it works:

```
//if (connection != _videoConnection)
if ([connection.output connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] == nil)
    {
        bVideo = NO;
    }
```